# Token is not valid while using multiple multi triggers in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have tried the following MultiTriggers in a style of targetType = ListBoxItem.

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiTrigger.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Background, Converter ={StaticResource stringToBrushConverter}}" />
    </MultiTrigger.Setters>
</MultiTrigger>
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiTrigger.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black}" />
    </MultiTrigger.Setters>
</MultiTrigger>
```

When I run my program I get the following error:

```
Token is not Valid
```

If I delete second trigger, my program works without any errors.

Basically I want to style a ListBox Item when mouse is over it, but I don't want to apply that style when Item is Selected as well as mouse is over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a Typo:

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black}" />
```

remove the extra `}`:

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
```

Comment: I was searching for that for a long time of 1 and half hour and you figured it out. Thanks.